# Setting up a dummy memory mapped IO in Embedded Unit-Tests with a template-based API

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, linker, embedded

I'm working on a template based API for accessing GPIO and other peripherals on stm32f7xx.
The API is based on "Real time c++ - efficient object-oriented and template microcontroller programming" by Christopher Kormanyos.

```cpp
// gpio.h
template <std::uintptr_t BASE, std::uint8_t PIN>
class Gpio final {...}

// main.cpp
// this is how the API is usally used.
// note that GPIOA_BASE is defined in stm header files and 
// is an uint that directly points to the memory mapped IO
using gpio_a0 = Framework::Stm32F7xx::Gpio::Gpio<GPIOA_BASE, 0>;
```

The book itself doesn't get into testing, IMO writing code without tests feels off. So I finally decided to catch up and get my CMake with Gtest up and running.

My issue is that the tests are compiled for a (host/not ARM)-plattform so I could run them in a pipeline. So I can't and shouldn't use the defines from the stm header files like `GPIOA_BASE`. As they would point to a location that is NOT available on the tests executing plattform. (It results in a `SIGSEGV` as I access memory I shouldn't)

My issue is now. How do I pass the Template a `uintptr_t` which points to a memory location of size: `GPIO_Typedef` and is also defined at compile time?

Is this even possible ? Are there other options ?

I tryed a few different versions all not working.
In the example below I hope I can futher elaborate what I need.

```cpp
class GpioFixture : public ::testing::Test {
};

static constexpr char mem[sizeof(GPIO_TypeDef)] {};
static constexpr std::uintptr_t memptr = &mem; // <- this is not working

TEST_F(GpioFixture, ...){
    using gpio_a1 = Framework::Stm32F7xx::Gpio::Gpio<memptr, 1>;
    gpio_a1 a1 {...};

    // perform test

}
```

**Edit:**
So the main issue is that I need some memory available at POINT X and get the address of it at compile time.

So i could simple do a `using gpio_a0 = Framework::Stm32F7xx::Gpio::Gpio<0x..., 0>;`

Maybe it is possible to archieve that using a linker script ?
Creating a section and exporting the start of the section ?
I'm not sure as I don't really know if this would work with the virtual memory addresses resolved by the OS?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve isn't possible at the moment and, looking at the current state of [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) and [std::bless](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html), most likely never will be. I'd also advice against writing "unit tests" for hardware abstractions. If you really must you could make the unitptr_t template parameter auto. That way you could pass actual pointer types instead of integers. Since you'll have to reinterpret_cast inside your Gpio class anyhow it wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly your main point is that this would cause issues as typecasting some memory without a call to new is undefined behaviour in c++ ?
But the most embedded MCU's headers work that ways as the just define a memory location and then cast a pointer to that location as a type. like `GPIO_TypeDef`

With `auto` I'll get an error message in runtime once I use the Template parameter inside the class. `reinterpret_cast from type ‘const char (*)[40]’ to type ‘GPIO_TypeDef*’ casts away qualifiers auto base = reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(BASE);`

Comment: I think if it is somehow possible to define a VMA that is always available I should be fine with the `uintptr_t`
I would zero out the bits before accessing them.

Comment: I know that this pattern is used everywhere but technically it's still UB although pretty much every sane compiler will do as expected. The error you mentioned will disappear when you make the memory location you point to non-constexpr.

Comment: It actually works when using auto and a non-constexpr.

With auto I assume it is possible to simply pass a pointer instead of a `uintptr_t`. Further more I can easily change the `... mem...` to an actual `GPIO_TypeDef`

But I quite don't really understand why this fails when using `constexpr`. Can you maybe explain that ?
+ Write an actual answer so I can Reward you the 100 Bounty ? As I can't give you the bounty for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static constexpr char mem[sizeof(GPIO_TypeDef)] {};
static constexpr std::uintptr_t memptr = &mem; // <- this is not working
```

The problem with this code snippet is that you'd need a constexpr reinterpret_cast for the second line which is not permitted by the language. I know that this is a very common pattern for embedded devices and I personally had hoped for either [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) or [std::bless](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r3.html#idiomatic-c-code-as-c) to consider this but it seems like we'll have to do without.

There is still a way to get this to compile on your host machine though. You could use an auto template parameter like this:

```
template <auto BASE, std::uint8_t PIN>
class Gpio {};
```

Member functions of the Gpio class will have to make heavy use of reinterpret_cast anyhow so e.g. set might look like this:

```
static void set(uint32_t bit) {
  reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef*>(BASE)->BSRR = 1u << bit;
}
```

Since the template parameter BASE now accepts pointers you could even pass a pointer to an instance of GPIO_TypeDef directly (as a nice side effect this also solves the UB problem since the parameter now actually is GPIO_TypeDef*):

```
GPIO_TypeDef mem{};
Gpio<&mem, 0u> gpio_a;
```

And on your target you can keep using the definitions from the STM32F7 header:

```
Gpio<GPIOA_BASE, 0u> gpio_a;
```

And also answering the question from your last comment

> But I quite don't really understand why this fails when using constexpr.

That might have two reasons.

Creating a constexpr instance of GPIO_TypeDef also means passing a pointer to a const object to the template class. In case you already have any member functions defined which reinterpret_cast to GPIO_TypeDef* you'd get an error that you're trying to cast the const qualifier away.

Also you can't create constexpr instances of [non-literal types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). GPIO_TypeDef is non-literal as its members are all volatile (hidden behind a define called __IO).